# Docker VS Native installation on a server. How to recover from downtime mysql/mariadb without data lloss

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

Fellows,
I have the following assumption:

I have an application X (let us e wordpresss) running into a docker container and links to another docker container running mysql. Annd for some reason I lose the database it there a way to recover without any data loss from the latest changes?

For some reason (not sure if true or not) any file changes into docker container it automatically is lost. Therefore is the database is into a docker container then anything that is into the db is automatically lost.

Instead if mysql is running on the server and the database is down I just an restart the server and then is ok because the changes into the filesystem are written. And before make the system live i can also force a backup to have the latest changes.

In booth cases of course somehow I managed to get a nice backup in a daily basis. And in booth cases I want the minimum data loss.

And of course I understand that maybe data corruption in the second option. I want to have the latest written data even if corrupted.

Comment: I do not want replication i want when I will start again from a fail (server closed) my application to recover from the  point it was before.

Comment: If the server comes back up, and if you were using InnoDB, that is what happens.

Comment: If Docker loses everything, you need to have another copy somewhere else, hence some form of Replication.